# Understanding a definition about double-dual spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Let $V$ a $\mathbb{F}$-space, and define the function $\Phi:V\rightarrow V^{**}$ by

$$\Phi(v)(f)=f(v)\quad\; \textrm{for all}\;\quad v\in V,\; f\in V^{*} $$

I didn't understand that definition, because it's seen that $\Phi$ is defined like it was $\Phi:V\times V^{*}\rightarrow V^{**}$. Do I have a different $\Phi$ for each $f$? (I think the answer is yes).

Now, let $\alpha=(v_{i})_{i\in I}$ a linearly independent family in $V$. Define the nullifier of $\alpha$ by

$$\alpha^{0}=\{f\in V^{**}:f(v_{i})=0\;\forall  i\in I\}. $$

I want to prove that $\textrm{Span}(\alpha)\subset\Phi^{-1}\left((\alpha^{0})^{0}\right)$.

By definition, $(\alpha^{0})^{0}=\{g\in V^{**}:g(f_{i})=0\;\forall i\in I\}$, where $f_{i}(v_{j})=\delta_{i,j}=
\begin{cases}
1,\;\textrm{if}\; i=j \\
0, \;\textrm{if}\; i\neq j
\end{cases}.$

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The double dual space $V^{**}$ is the dual of $V^*$ then and element $\psi \in V^{**}$ is a linear map $\psi \colon V^* \longrightarrow  \mathbb{F}$.

For an element $v\in V$ we can define $f\in V^* \mapsto f(v) \in \mathbb{F}$ which gives and element of $V^{**}$.
Therefore we define the map
$$
\Phi \colon V \longrightarrow V^{**}
$$
by
$$
\Phi(v) \colon V^* \longrightarrow \mathbb{F}, \, f \mapsto f(v) 
$$

For the second part, and element of $V^{**}$ may act on $V^{*}$ not on $V$ unless you give more structure.